# What are these meta tags?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, meta

```
meta charset="utf-8"              
meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"         
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
```

What do each of these do? I know that `<meta name="author" content="">` is for search engines?

Comment: have you google searched them? One is for IE, the other is mobile device scaling to normalize view. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e

Comment: No I have not googled as I have gotten better responses here.

Comment: it always begins with google search or you will get reemed with downvotes. Not a way to maintain a healthy account on this site

Comment: I personally dont care about an account on a website. Especially virtual down votes. Thanks I got a great response.

Comment: Do you realize the quality of the responses you get improves with a healthier account? I understand not caring about a virtual score, but there's no point in posting if all you get is ridicule... except you just said you got a great response, so toucee, but none the less, higher rep on the site would lead to more complete and more helpful answers

Comment: @user3558061 You may not care about virtual downvotes but if you acquire enough of them you'll be banned. -1 for a bad attitude.

Comment: Yeah I guess that is true, I mean the response was perfect. When I googled around I was led to some confusing stuff. This was a straight answer. I mean, my questions are lame anyways since I am new to HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### **charset**: Specifies the character encoding for the HTML document.

---

#### **http-equiv**: Provides an HTTP header for the information/value of the content attribute.

Edge mode tells Internet Explorer to display content in the highest mode available. With Internet Explorer 9, this is equivalent to IE9 mode. If a future release of Internet Explorer supported a higher compatibility mode, pages set to edge mode would appear in the highest mode supported by that version. Those same pages would still appear in IE9 mode when viewed with Internet Explorer 9.

---

#### **name**: Specifies a name for the metadata.

---

#### The viewport meta tag: the key to preparing a page for mobile devices optimization

**width**: The width of the virtual viewport of the device. Enter a number (pixels assumed), or the keyword "device-width" to set the viewport to the physical width of the device's screen.

**initial-scale**: The initial zoom of the webpage, where a value of 1.0 means no zoom.

---

For more information, see [HTML meta tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp).